# Cannot identify and manipulate this website 'popup' advice please?

Tags: python, selenium, web, scripting

So I'm automating Exchange mailbox creation with our email hosted by a 3rd party. They use a software called Hosting Controller which gives me the ability to create new mailboxes. Except it's all manual, So Im working on a Python+Selenium script to automate this process.

I'm hitting a roadblock where I'm unable to identify this popup so I can manipulate it.  I believe it's JQuery but the

> Alert = alert.switch_to.alert()

Refuses to work.. I get tracebacks. I then examined switch_to.element/frame/window but I couldn't get any of those to work.

I'm very new to this stuff being this is only the second Python script I've ever tried outside of training coursework.

Here is a short video on what I'm talking about: https://streamable.com/3dx3z5

Comment: unable to access video or streamablewebsite. Could you share software official link

Comment: I assume you are referring to the Hosting Controller, it's at  https://www.hostingcontroller.com

Comment: please share source code or try using [selenium ide](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium-ide/) . check Resilient Tests feature.

Answer (score 0):

So, from looking at your video, the pop-up form that you're seeing is a modal. Without having access to HostingController.com or login credentials, I cannot find the `xpath` for you. 
So, what you will need to do is look at the `HTML` source using the Browser's Dev Tools / DOM ( F12 if you are using the new Chromium Edge or Google Chrome itself ) and check to see if the modal is displaying. I submitted an answer to a question in another thread regarding pop-up modal ( [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64325242/blocking-login-overlay-window-when-scraping-web-page-using-selenium/64329775#64329775) ). 
I hope this guidance helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. So I wont lie, I have no idea what a modal is at this point but I will google it after this. 
So I stumbled onto a fix, of course after saying that I might have just discovered a work-around. So I ended up replacing the xpath value with a "Full Xpath" as copied from Chrome. I was using Firefox with this exclusively but the onyl copy options from the F12 tools is 'Copy Xpath', I just stumbled across it in Chrome where it said both Xpath and Full Xpath. Turns out the Full Xpath worked and allowed the remaining lines to manipulate that 'popup' area.